# Typescript: How to use macros which are available in .xlsm file in .xlsx files using typescript and nodejs libraries

Tags: node.js, excel, typescript, selenium-webdriver

I am using typescript-selenium for automation. During the test, an xlsx file gets downloaded with huge data and we need to do some operations on the it. We are using an xlsm file which contains lot of macros, based on the use case I want to use macros from xlsm file and consume it in xlsx file.
Any on help on this is much appreciated

I am newbie to typescript and macros, need some inputs